# Node JS Multer Multiple Files Req.File Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

FIXED: ( NO req.file ) ( YES req.files )

---

My project need multiple files upload,

If i single image upload working, multiple image upload working ( upload to files ) and i need req.file.filename because i write mysql this image road.

Req.File = Undefined..

```
  // Sinle image upload and write mysql..
  Router.post('/uax_items_addOne', Upload.single('fileUrl'), Controller.Cnt_AddOne);

  // Multiple image upload and undefined req.file
  Router.post('/uax_items_multipleFile', Upload.array('fileUrl', 12), Controller.Cnt_MultipleFile);

  // This is controller
  exports.Cnt_MultipleFile = (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.file); // This is write "undefined"
  }

  // This is my Storage
  const Storage = Multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, './uax_Uploads/images');
      },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, 'img-' + Date.now() + Path.extname(file.originalname));
      }
  });
  var Upload = Multer({
      storage: Storage
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple files are provided to you in `req.files` (note the `s` at the end).

If you want to simplify your POST queries, I would recommend using Multer's `.fields()` function, that let you group incoming file params (post-processing is done, both, with the `files` field).

For example:

```
upload.fields([
  { name: 'one_tag_param' , maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'multiple_tag_param' , maxCount: 12 }
])
```